# jQuery autocomplet from database with asp

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp-classic, autocomplete, sql-server-2008-r2

I have asp page, and I need to show a table of data from Sql Server database, I want to select the city names from 2 text areas for example(source and destination) and then show all the informations of this row.
here is a copy of the autocomplete.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"Shanghai",
"Shenzhen",
"Casablanca",
"Jeddah",
"Paris",
"PHP",
"London",
"Tokyo",
"Jeddah",
"Istambul"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the page index.asp:

```
    ....
    <!--#include file="autocomplete.html"--> <label for="tags"> POD </label>
<input id="tags" />
    <br>
```

I want from the jQuery autocomplete to get the source and the destination from my database not that way:

```
var availableTags = [
"Shanghai",
"Shenzhen",
"Casablanca",
"Jeddah",
"Paris",
"PHP",
"London",
"Tokyo",
"Jeddah",
"Istambul"
];
```

How could I do this ??

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Classic ASP just as you would for the form.  Try putting your code brackets inside the array list like so...

```js
var availableTags = [<%=GetCities() %>];
```

Your `GetCities()` function would then output to the `Response` object the list of required cities.

-- Edit --

The following code has not been fully tested.  You may also need to modify parts that are appropriate to your needs:

```vb
const C_NO_DATA = "NO_DATA"              'Used when no data is returned to a consuming routine
const C_ERROR   = "ERROR"                'Used when an error is generated - to be fed to the comsuming routine

'GetDataSet
'    Returns a table of data based on the supplied SQL statement and connection string.
'Parameters:
'    sqlString (string) - The SQL string to be sent.
'    connString (string) - The database connection string.
'Usage:
'    dataSet = GetDataSet(sqlString, connString)
'Description:
'    This function generates a table of information in a 2 dimensional array.  The first dimension represents the columns
'    and the second the rows.  If an error occurs while the routine is executing the array and the base index (0,0) is set 
'    to C_ERROR, (0,1) to the VBScript error index, and (0,2) to the VBScript error description.
function GetDataSet(sqlString, connString)
    'Initialise...
    dim returnVal, rsData
    on error resume next
        'Define and open the recordset object...
        set rsData = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        rsData.Open sqlString, connString, 0, 1, 1
        'Initialise an empty value for the containing array...
        redim returnVal(0,0)
        returnVal(0,0) = C_NO_DATA
        'Deal with any errors...
        if not rsData.EOF and not rsData.BOF then
            'Store the data...
            returnVal = rsData.GetRows()
            'Tidy up...
            rsData.close
            set rsData = nothing
            select case err.number
                case 3021    'No data returned
                    'Do nothing as the initial value will still exist (C_NO_DATA)
                case 0        'No error
                    'Do nothing as data has been returned
                case else
                    redim returnVal(4,0)
                    returnVal(0,0) = C_ERROR
                    returnVal(1,0) = err.number
                    returnVal(2,0) = err.description
                    returnVal(3,0) = sqlString
                    returnVal(4,0) = connString
            end select
        end if
    on error goto 0
    'Return the array...
    GetDataSet = returnVal
end function

function GetCities()
    dim sql, tCity, rc, max, rv
    sql = _
        "SELECT " & _
            "'""' + city_name + '""' AS city " & _
        "FROM  " & _
            "clkj_freight  " & _
        "WHERE  " & _
            "pol = '" & replace(request.querystring("q"), "'", "''") & "'"
    tCity = GetDataSet(sql, conn)
    if tCity(0, 0) = C_ERROR or tCity(0, 0) = C_NO_DATA then rv = tcity(0, 0)
    max = UBound(tCity, 2) '2 is the second dimension of the array
    for rc = 0 to max
        Response.Write(tCity(rc, 0))
        If rc<max then Response.Write(",")
    Next 'rc
    'If an error is encountered or no data is returned then notify the user (this behaviour may be changed if necessary)...
    GetCities = rv
end function
```

Comment: What should I do in `GetCities()` function? my connexion page is like so:  `response.expires=-1
set rs=server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
sql="SELECT * FROM clkj_freight WHERE POL="
sql=sql & "'" & request.querystring("q") & "'"
rs.open sql,conn,1,1 `

is this correct??

Comment: If that code retrieves your list of cities then all you'd need to do is read them into an array, add speech marks to the beginning and end of each entry and then use `Join` (using a comma as the separator) to make your list of cities. (You could even put the speech marks in the SQL to speed things up.

Comment: Can you please give me a code example of how to do this, because I really don't know what to do ??!

Comment: You could try the code I've put in there, but it is untested (I just don't have time).  The `GetDataSet` function is particularly useful as it will port to any other classic ASP apps that you have.  The first element of the array can hold a value of `C_ERROR`, `C_NO_DATA` or any other text and should always be checked. If there's an error then the details are held in the adjacent cells (0,1..0,4).